# Difference between wildcare generic vs no generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

In Java, what is the difference between:

```
public void foo(List lst);
```

and

```
public void foo(List<?> lst);
```

Comment: @Varsha No. Please re-read the question as this has to do with wildcard vs non-generics.

Comment: It's an unbounded wildcard: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: The second suppresses the warnings about not using generics.

Comment: @Raedwalk Please link to the answer then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK:

Just using List lst is a raw type, therefore not typesafe. It will only generate a runtime error when the casting is bad. We want a compile time error when the cast is bad. Not recommended to use. Additional information on raw types : [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

In the case of List: is an unbounded wildcard.

Comment: I accepted this because the answer is inside one of the answers that you linked to. Thank you, as everyone else has been horribly inept at providing any semblance of a correct response.

Answer (score 0):

The first version is a 'List of any type'. This is not generic, not safe and not recommended.

The second version is a 'List of unknown type'. This means you will `get` objects of the most general type `Object`, and won't be able to `add` anything else than `null`. Since these are the only type safe operations when nothing is known about the type.

You might think the version version is more succinct, and it is. However duck typed languages tend to be more succinct, but that doesn't make them the right choice. Using the raw `List` is only possible due to backwards compatibility, and you will get a compiler warning.

For more fun, consider the following types, and how they differ from your two:

- `foo(List<Object> list)`
- `foo(List<? extends Object> list)`
- `foo(List<? super Object> list)`
- `foo(List<? super Iterable<? extends Object>> list)`